# What would be the suggested material for blocking EM waves of a 600V 160kW 5kHz coil?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am building up a reactor for heating material inside, but I need its EM waves not to interfere with the rest of my near circuitry.  Its working conditions are:

- 600 VAC
- 300 A
- 160kW
- 5kHz

What would be the best material to "wrap it in" in order to block the possible EM interference inside?  Some people suggested me using lead, others copper, stainless-steel, etc.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: This is more an engineering than a physics questions (there will probably be tables for this sort of thing) - you might be better off asking the question at electronics.stackexchange.

Comment: From my point of view, one should not only be concerned with shielding of the reactor volume (for which I suggest a two-layered and well soldered box of a good conductor, such as copper plates), but also the ground loops and noise transmitted through the mains. The latter effects can even present more trouble.

Comment: dominecf thanks, in fact my idea is to ground the cover that I will put around the reactor.  Also, I am considering isolation with a 1:1 transformer to prevent noise returning to the source.  What would you suggest other than this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is an induction furnace? The problem is that 5kHz is quite a low frequency and nearfield effects will tend to dominate. It becomes more of a magnetic shielding problem. So I would guess soft iron might be your best best, grounded to act as an EM shield.

I am also assuming a sinusoidal waveform. If you are using something like a square wave or chopped mains much higher frequency components will be present.

Comment: You are right, it is actually an induction furnace.  It is a normal sinusoidal waveform.  I will forget about lead and go for your suggestion with a grounded cover of iron or copper.  What I'm not sure at this point is about the skin depth effect to absorb the most of the EM waves.

Comment: The biggest problem at that frequency is transformer coupling, not radiated field. Also be careful not to get your shielding too close to the coil, or you will be creating a 1 turn transformer using your case. Which is seriously bad.

Comment: So, would you suggest to rise the frequency of the signal and then translate the problem to an RF shielding?  Or simply isolating the body of the reactor with an EM shield and using a 1:1 transformer at the input?

Comment: It depends on what you wish to "hide" from the coil signal. It will not propagate very far in open space. Are you sure you need electromagnetic shielding at all? Maybe just keep sensitive equipment more than a couple of metres away? It might be best to run some experiments

Comment: Well, given the restricted space I have for the installation is why I thought about shielding.  Nevertheless, in general the components are basically switches and relays.  Maybe the main concern will be some PLCs, but as far as I know they come roughly protected to work in these environments.  But like as you say, tests must be done in order to achieve to the final model.  Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: What are the dimensions of the coil, number of turns? Water cooled?